# cannot update custom ratingbar android

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am trying to write code based on which I should update the rating in steps of 1 as I am getting integer values for Rating. Here is the code for the same

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp" >

    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/PriceRating"
    style="@style/foodRatingBarSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="1"
    android:stepSize="0.25"
    android:max="5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code in the style file:

```
<style name="foodRatingBarSmall" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/foodratingbar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
</style>
```

Here are the foodratingbar file

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/foodratingbar_fill"
    />
    <item android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/foodratingbar_fill" />
    <item android:id="@+id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/foodratingbar_empty" />

</layer-list>
```

And here is the code for foodratingbar_fill:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/dollar" />

        <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/dollar" />

        <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/dollar" />

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/dollar" />

    </selector>
```

where dollar is a png image

The problem with my code is that I cannot get it to update to the required number of stars and I see vague values of the number of stars being displayed on android. I would like to know how I can display one dollar image for 1 rating with a maximum of 5

Comment: refer this link : http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/08/android-ratingbar-example.html

Comment: Thanks Bala, but this is not custom rating bar example also this rating bar is updated by user input. Sorry forgot to mention but in my example the rating gets updated by results obtained from a web service

Comment: I am still stuck with this.. Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks